# "Open Lightning Resources" option in developer console is greyed out

Tags: lightning-aura-components, developer-console

[image: Open Lightning Resources - option greyed out]

This is from my developer org. What option I need to set to get that option active? I need this option to browse "Lightning components" in Developer console.

Comment: Which browser are you using it ? Do you see any errors in console ?

Comment: I do not see the option - 'Open Lightning Resources' in my developer console (the org where I'm looking) - @MohithShrivastava. This screenshot is from my personal developer console.

Comment: I meant browser (IE or chrome or Firefox or any other ) ? Also when did you sign up the org ? And are you system admin of the org?

Comment: Got it I was on chrome. It is work related sandbox and I'm not admin of this org, that was the main issue over here. I was asked to figure out what permission is missing on my own to get that option in developer console, so that they can give that permission. Instead of wasting my time on this I could ask them to give me admin profile which is the best solution for this issue. @MohithShrivastava